# google cloud storage access denied with allAuthenticatedUsers

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I use Reactjs to create a website and host it on Firebase, and set `serviceAccount.json` with `firebase-admin` and `@google-cloud/storage` on Google Cloud Functions to handle functions. Website has a `<iframe>` element, it will load `aaa.html` link url from bucket in Google Cloud Storage. Bucket of GCS is set to `allAuthenticatedUsers`. Upload `aaa.html` using `predefinedAcl:'authenticatedRead'`. Website could login with `firebaseui-web-react`. I only got access denied when I load `aaa.html`.

```
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access denied.</Message>
    <Details>
        Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to 
        bucket/path/aaa.html.
</Details>
</Error>
```

How can I access correctly?

Comment: How are you accessing the URL? With those permissions only authenticated Google account holders can access the file.

Comment: I tried fetch in front, but I have no idea how to connect GCS with authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Your request is not authenticated, you are anonymous. Be sure that you have a Google account (email, service account,..)

Your user have to be known be Google (or Cloud Identity) for being considered as known/authenticated.
With firebase auth, your user can be known, and authenticated by external service (Facebook, Github,...) but GCS only trust Google authenticated account.

A solution is to create a service account for your backend. To provide GCS Bucket access to this service service account and to serve file to your user through your backend.

Comment: Users can login with `firebaseui-web-react`. Do I authenticated when I login with `firebaseui-web-react`?

Comment: Hmmm, I think not. Indeed, you perform an authentication flow with identity provider (via OAuth2, most of time). Thanks to this authentication, you get claims and you (or firebase-auth) generate a token to use in the next communication. However, you aren't authenticated against Google registry. For example, an authentication performed with Facebook, facebook know you, but not Google, and GCS shouldn't trust you. I update my answer ;)

Comment: There's plenty of information [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication) about how to authenticate to the Storage API and includes links for Firebase authentication.

Comment: I have no idea after read `Cloud Storage authentication`, the sample code is too short for me to know what to do. Could you please give me some simple code? I have edited the question to describe more of my situation.

Comment: I can't give you any code but you could try having a look at the firebase [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/start) for using Firebase with GCS and see if that helps you.